# Is there a dummy guide for using Savon with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, soap, savon

Does anyone have a real dummy guide to using Savon with Ruby to consume SOAP web services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official documentation is pretty good, isn't it enough? if so, why?

http://rubiii.github.com/savon/